# codeignitor Halogy rewrite issue

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, cms, codeigniter

I'm using a CMS called [halogy](http://www.halogy.com/) built off codeignitor but can't figure out how to get it to work correctly in IIS. I think its related to the rewrite from Apache (works fine on Apache) heres the .htacess file contents

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

Hoping someone can convert this into config file for IIS, thanks all.